# Finite sum of beta prime iid random variables

Tags: distributions, beta-distribution, convolution, iid, sum

The beta prime distribution is infinitely divisible, as proved in [Steutel and van Harn, 2003 (Appendix B)](https://books.google.com.bn/books?id=5ddskbtvVjMC). Sadly, in this book, there is no expression of the parameters of the distribution of $n$ variables iid following a beta prime distribution, as it is done for some other distributions (normal, gamma, etc).

I cannot find how to derive it by myself. As an example, I am trying to derive the probability of the sum of two variables, and I am stuck in solving the basic convolution integral:

$$
f_{X+Y}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)dx=\int_0^{z}\frac{1}{B(a,b)^2}\frac{(x(z-x))^{a-1}}{((1+x)(1+z-x))^{a+b}}dx
$$

This distribution must be beta prime and I want to compute the parameters of this joint distribution. Is there a mean to get it from the convolution of PDF? Is there another mean to get directly the parameters of the beta prime pdf of the sum of n random variables iid following a beta prime distribution?

Comment: cross posting is not allowed. please delete this question on mse

Comment: @JoeyDoey I don't intend to cross-post but I would like to transfer it from mse and I don't find how to. Not enough reputation maybe? I am deleting the one on mse right now. Thanks for the moderation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ with $X_i\overset{\text{i.i.d}}{\sim}\beta^\prime(\alpha,\beta)$ and $Z=X_1+\dots+X_n$. It follows from linearity of the expected value that
$$
\mathsf EZ=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathsf EX_i=n\mathsf EX=\frac{n\alpha}{\beta-1},\quad\beta>1.
$$
Furthermore, by mutual independence of the $X_i$'s we have
$$
\mathsf{Var}Z=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathsf{Var}X_i=n\mathsf{Var}X=\frac{n\alpha(\alpha+\beta-1)}{(\beta-2)(\beta-1)^2},\quad\beta>2.
$$
Since we know $Z\sim\beta^\prime(\gamma,\delta)$ we may write the system of equations
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{n\alpha}{\beta-1} &=\frac{\gamma}{\delta-1}\\
\frac{n\alpha(\alpha+\beta-1)}{(\beta-2)(\beta-1)^2} &=\frac{\gamma(\gamma+\delta-1)}{(\delta-2)(\delta-1)^2}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Solving this system for $\gamma$ and $\delta$ subsequently yields the following result:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\gamma &=\frac{\alpha  n \left(\alpha +\beta ^2-2 \beta +\alpha  \beta  n-2
   \alpha  n+1\right)}{(\beta -1) (\alpha +\beta -1)}\\
\delta &=\frac{2 \alpha +\beta
   ^2-\beta +\alpha  \beta  n-2 \alpha  n}{\alpha +\beta -1}.
\end{aligned}
$$
With some algebra you may be able to simplify these expressions.

**Update:**

Based on the discussion surrounding the exactness/correctness of the results I decided to perform an experiment in MATLAB.  Here is the code used which performs the simulation for $\alpha=\beta=15$ and $n=5$:

```
a = 15; %alpha
b = 15; %beta
n = 5;
c = (a*n*(a-2*b-2*a*n+b^2+a*b*n+1))/((b-1)*(a+b-1)); %gamma
d = (2*a-b-2*a*n+b^2+a*b*n)/(a+b-1); %delta

Xdata = 1./betarnd(a,b,1e6,n)-1;
Xn = sum(Xdata,2); %Xn = X_1+X_2+...+X_n
ax = linspace(0,max(Xn),256);
f_Xn = @(x) x.^(c-1).*(1+x).^(-c-d)/beta(c,d);

figure
hold on
histogram(Xn,64,'normalization','pdf')
plot(ax,f_Xn(ax),'Color',[0,0,0],'LineWidth',1.5)
xlabel(['X_' num2str(n)])
ylabel('density')
box on
hold off
```

Here we see that the histogram does indeed agree with the theoretical beta prime distribution with parameters $\gamma$ and $\delta$ as derived above. I tried other values of $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $n$ with similar results.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed computation. After performing a test with two and three such variables, it appears that this result is only approximate, so that I figure out that I was wrong assuming that the sum is beta prime distributed. Note that the approximation is worst as `n` increases.

Comment: I found two errors, one with my code (which is similar to yours) and one with yours, exactly at the same line (coincidence!): when we want to generate $X_n$  following the beta prime distribution. So the correct way to do is `Xdata = 1./betarnd(a,b,1e6,n)-1; Xdata = 1./Xdata;`. In my case, I put extra parentheses. In both cases, the resulting variables are following $\beta'(d,c)$ and not $\beta'(c,d)$. So I delete my little extra comment, and your answer will be perfect as soon as the little mistake will be corrected! Thnak you very much Aaron.